# autoarima train and test, grouped by id in r

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm trying to forecast time series with auto.arima. What I need is to split in train and test data to see the model metrics. my date range is between December 2016 and January 2020.  I need the train data to be until December 2018 and the test after this.

Along with this, I need the metrics RMSE and MSE for each id. 
This is an example of my data:

```
x<-    tibble::tribble(
      ~ID,        ~Date,  ~Value,
       1L, "01-12-2016",     48L,
       1L, "01-01-2017",  10055L,
       1L, "01-02-2017",    650L,
       1L, "01-03-2017",   8255L,
       1L, "01-04-2017",   3680L,
       1L, "01-05-2017",   2180L,
       1L, "01-06-2017",   2790L,
       1L, "01-07-2017",   3805L,
       1L, "01-08-2017",   2811L,
       1L, "01-09-2017",   -225L,
       1L, "01-10-2017",   -232L,
       1L, "01-11-2017",   -243L,
       1L, "01-12-2017",   -217L,
       1L, "01-01-2018",   -256L,
       1L, "01-02-2018",   -277L,
       1L, "01-03-2018",     -3L,
       1L, "01-04-2018",   -247L,
       1L, "01-05-2018",     88L,
       1L, "01-06-2018",   -260L,
       1L, "01-07-2018",   -228L,
       1L, "01-08-2018",   -285L,
       1L, "01-09-2018",   -321L,
       1L, "01-10-2018",   -265L,
       1L, "01-11-2018",   -302L,
       1L, "01-12-2018", -11968L,
       1L, "01-01-2019",   5435L,
       1L, "01-02-2019",   6694L,
       1L, "01-03-2019",   4750L,
       1L, "01-04-2019",   3747L,
       1L, "01-05-2019",   3727L,
       1L, "01-06-2019",   3252L,
       1L, "01-07-2019",   1691L,
       1L, "01-08-2019",   2489L,
       1L, "01-09-2019",   -182L,
       1L, "01-10-2019",   3926L,
       1L, "01-11-2019",    326L,
       1L, "01-12-2019",  -1047L,
       1L, "01-01-2020",     14L,
       2L, "01-12-2016",   -241L,
       2L, "01-01-2017",   -262L,
       2L, "01-02-2017",   -231L,
       2L, "01-03-2017",   -203L,
       2L, "01-04-2017",   -226L,
       2L, "01-05-2017",   -223L,
       2L, "01-06-2017",   -300L,
       2L, "01-07-2017",   -259L,
       2L, "01-08-2017",   -241L,
       2L, "01-09-2017",   -225L,
       2L, "01-10-2017",   -227L,
       2L, "01-11-2017",   -243L,
       2L, "01-12-2017",   -217L,
       2L, "01-01-2018",   -256L,
       2L, "01-02-2018",   -277L,
       2L, "01-03-2018",      0L,
       2L, "01-04-2018",   -247L,
       2L, "01-05-2018",   -274L,
       2L, "01-06-2018",   -264L,
       2L, "01-07-2018",   -227L,
       2L, "01-08-2018",   -275L,
       2L, "01-09-2018",   -325L,
       2L, "01-10-2018",   -269L,
       2L, "01-11-2018",   -306L,
       2L, "01-12-2018",   -264L,
       2L, "01-01-2019",   -308L,
       2L, "01-02-2019",   -332L,
       2L, "01-03-2019",   -260L,
       2L, "01-04-2019",   -300L,
       2L, "01-05-2019",   -302L,
       2L, "01-06-2019",   -291L,
       2L, "01-07-2019",   -284L,
       2L, "01-08-2019",   -288L,
       2L, "01-09-2019",   -272L,
       2L, "01-10-2019",      0L,
       2L, "01-11-2019",      0L,
       2L, "01-12-2019", -17107L,
       2L, "01-01-2020",   3500L,
       3L, "01-12-2016",   1940L,
       3L, "01-01-2017",   1753L,
       3L, "01-02-2017",   2758L,
       3L, "01-03-2017",   2539L,
       3L, "01-04-2017",  -9078L,
       3L, "01-05-2017",   5215L,
       3L, "01-06-2017",   1796L,
       3L, "01-07-2017",  -8424L,
       3L, "01-08-2017",  19868L,
       3L, "01-09-2017",  10707L,
       3L, "01-10-2017",   8985L,
       3L, "01-11-2017",   3058L,
       3L, "01-12-2017",   2469L,
       3L, "01-01-2018",     21L,
       3L, "01-02-2018",   1039L,
       3L, "01-03-2018",   2875L,
       3L, "01-04-2018",  -2678L,
       3L, "01-05-2018",   1515L,
       3L, "01-06-2018",   2651L,
       3L, "01-07-2018",  -5014L,
       3L, "01-08-2018",    299L,
       3L, "01-09-2018",   1755L,
       3L, "01-10-2018",   5009L,
       3L, "01-11-2018",   2857L,
       3L, "01-12-2018",   2909L,
       3L, "01-01-2019",   1353L,
       3L, "01-02-2019",   2337L,
       3L, "01-03-2019",   3019L,
       3L, "01-04-2019",   -531L,
       3L, "01-05-2019",  -1055L,
       3L, "01-06-2019",   1706L,
       3L, "01-07-2019",   -507L,
       3L, "01-08-2019",   2234L,
       3L, "01-09-2019",    890L,
       3L, "01-10-2019",     94L,
       3L, "01-11-2019",  -1781L,
       3L, "01-12-2019", 102590L,
       3L, "01-01-2020",    471L,
       4L, "01-12-2016",   2658L,
       4L, "01-01-2017",   2344L,
       4L, "01-02-2017",   2728L,
       4L, "01-03-2017",    -58L,
       4L, "01-04-2017",   -226L,
       4L, "01-05-2017",     -5L,
       4L, "01-06-2017",   -300L,
       4L, "01-07-2017",   -259L,
       4L, "01-08-2017",   -241L,
       4L, "01-09-2017",   -225L,
       4L, "01-10-2017",   -229L,
       4L, "01-11-2017",   -243L,
       4L, "01-12-2017",   -217L,
       4L, "01-01-2018",   -245L,
       4L, "01-02-2018",   -277L,
       4L, "01-03-2018",   -155L,
       4L, "01-04-2018",   5437L,
       4L, "01-05-2018",   2866L,
       4L, "01-06-2018",   3091L,
       4L, "01-07-2018",   3669L,
       4L, "01-08-2018",    311L,
       4L, "01-09-2018",   4120L,
       4L, "01-10-2018",   2357L,
       4L, "01-11-2018",  -4759L,
       4L, "01-12-2018",   4220L,
       4L, "01-01-2019",   2730L,
       4L, "01-02-2019",   2515L,
       4L, "01-03-2019",   2560L,
       4L, "01-04-2019",   2864L,
       4L, "01-05-2019",   1935L,
       4L, "01-06-2019",    938L,
       4L, "01-07-2019",   3268L,
       4L, "01-08-2019",   3232L,
       4L, "01-09-2019",   3347L,
       4L, "01-10-2019",   4241L,
       4L, "01-11-2019",   -247L,
       4L, "01-12-2019",    179L,
       4L, "01-01-2020",   2542L
      )

x<-as.data.frame(x)
```

I tried with dplyr:

```
x %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  do(fit=auto.arima(.$Value,seasonal = F,stepwise = F,approximation = F),
     fit_forecast=forecast(auto.arima(.$Value,seasonal = F,stepwise = F,approximation = F),h=12))
```

But I don't know how to add step of train and test and the metrics. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already answered the same question at https://community.rstudio.com/t/autoarima-train-and-test-grouped-by-id-in-r/66400, but for the record here it is again.

This is much easier to do with the tsibble and fable packages, like this.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)
library(fable)

# Turn x into a tsibble object
x <- x %>%
  mutate(Date = yearmonth(dmy(Date))) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = Date, key = ID)

# Use filter to create training set
# Then fit non-seasonal ARIMA models
fit <- x %>%
  filter(Date <= yearmonth("2018 Dec")) %>%
  model(ARIMA(Value ~ PDQ(0,0,0), stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE))

# Now forecast the test set and compute RMSE and MSE
fit %>%
  forecast(h = 13) %>%
  accuracy(x) %>%
  mutate(MSE = RMSE^2) %>%
  select(ID, RMSE, MSE)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      ID   RMSE        MSE
#>   <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1  9696.  94011195.
#> 2     2  4792.  22964718.
#> 3     3 27899. 778326636.
#> 4     4  1776.   3153398.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: When I try to do it, I got an error : 
Error: `as_tsibble()` doesn't know how to handle the yearmonth class yet.
Do you know why this happen? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It works using current CRAN versions of packages. Perhaps you have an old version of tsibble.

Comment: you we're right! I had to update my R, thank you! One last question, it is possible to plot the time series with the results for each id?

Comment: Yes, use autoplot().

Comment: Thanks! One last question, accuracy gives the average or the sum by id? for example the RMSE of ID 1 (9696) is the sum of all rows with his id?

Comment: It's a MSE, so *Mean* Squared Error.

Answer (score 0):

You simply subset your dataframe into training and test. Typically 80/20 split or 90/10 split. But in your case, since you seem to want specific dates, you can even hardcode the number of rows.

```
library("lubridate")
x$Date <- dmy(x$Date)
x <- x[order(x$Date),]
rownames(x) <- NULL
x.train <- x[1:139,]
x.text <- x[-(1:139),]
```

Typically the data is also sampled to get the 80/20 or 90/10. But in a timeseries, you want to want to simply split instead of sampling.

Comment: so the train and test are not by each time serie? 
In other words, do you not train until a date and then do a test with the following dates?

Comment: Yes, you train to a specific date and test on the rest of the data. In your case you have 152 observation. You can split it into 139, 13. 139 for training, 13 for test. If your model predicts Values for 13 test months (Jan 2019 to Jan 2020) close enough to the Values for those months you know, you have a good model. Then you can use it to predict Feb 2020 onwards. BTW, I just noticed your data is not sorted by time. Please do that first before splitting the data.

Comment: That was my question, I didn't know how to split by ID and date to do the train and test data. After the autoarima, how can I do the metrics?

Comment: You need to decide what metrics you are going to use to evaluate. MSE is a common, simple one. To calculate MSE, you find the difference between predicted value and observed value and square it. You fine the mean of those squares. Your model gets better as you reduce the MSE. Check this link for theory and alternate metrics. https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html